# SmartGWT application automation using QTP 11

Tags: qtp

Does QTP 11 support web application developed with SmartGWT on Firefox browser? Most of the SmartGWT functions such as dropdowns/checkbox does not work in firefox. Is there any patch that would help in this regard?

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

QTP supplies support for GWT separately, I don't know if this covers SmartGWT or not. In order to install additional GWT support go to the DVD and choose *Add-in Extensibility and Web 2.0 Toolkits* and install the GWT toolkit.